# Ng-Repeat List items repeating but are empty

Tags: javascript, angularjs

When I run the following in my browser I get two list items, but nothing is displayed within the two items. So the loop itself works but nothing is being pulled from my list.

I reedited my submission to show an accurate representation of my problem

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]>      <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html class="no-js"> <!--<![endif]-->

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
    <title></title>
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <style>
        body {
            padding-top: 50px;
            padding-bottom: 20px;
        }
    </style>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
    <script src="js/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/vendor/modernizr-2.6.2-respond-1.1.0.min.js"></script>
</head>


<!-- initial angular declaration -->
<body id="main" ng-app>


  <div ng-controller ="EductationCtrl">
    <ul class = "list-unstyled">
      <li ng-repeat = "school in schools">
            {{schools.name}}
       </li> 

    </ul>


  </div> 

  <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/vendor/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"><\/script>')</script>

    <script src="js/vendor/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <script src="js/main.js"></script>


</body>
```

Javascript

```
 function EductationCtrl($scope) {


    $scope.schools = [
    {name: 'university', major: 'Computer Science'},
    {name: 'College', major: 'Politcal Science and Finance'},

    ];

}
```

This is the end result:

```
<li ng-repeat="school in schools" class="ng-scope ng-binding">

</li>

<li ng-repeat="school in schools" class="ng-scope ng-binding">

</li>
```

Comment: `{{peole.name}}` < Nothing looks off to you there?

Comment: I'd also look at changing the name of your array to `peoples`. otherwise the markup looks confusing `people in people`. And that would open itself up to more problems down the road.

Comment: @enigmarm - Or `person in people`?

Comment: This works fine... just created a plunkr.  http://plnkr.co/edit/P9hhiL7OrBZkweuTrvw8?p=preview  I was shocked that it could handle `people in people`

Comment: You had a few errors in the way you constructed the plunker. Working: http://plnkr.co/edit/racKOVRRADd7jZm0qhPF?p=preview

Comment: @nix - Please read the comments under EnigmaRM's answer.

Comment: This is a typo... `schools` vs `school`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its a typo:

```
 {{schools.name}}
```

to

```
{{school.name}}
```

Comment: Thanks I feel like an idiot. I should probably be more careful in the way I name things. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo: <del>`{{peole.name}}`</del> should be `{{people.name}}`

[Plunker Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/MTSG0gHCZ4obO4PtISzm?p=preview)

Comment: This was just an example because I didn't want to show the data I was working with, and that wasn't a typo I had. I'll edit that. Thank you.

Comment: Well you may need to post more code then, as you can see from my Demo, what you have works.

Comment: @user3093175 - EnigmaRM demonstrates the code you posted works perfectly, so it's not a legitimate question to ask what's wrong, when nothing is wrong. Please provide code that accurately reproduces your problem.

Comment: @user3093175 - Please edit that into your question in place of the current code examples.

Comment: I edited the original submission to reflect what I have.